# Expanding tilde convenience paths when using quoted paths in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I have always used paths that aren't hardcoded inside quotes for my bash scripts. That way if the path (user inputed, user home dir, etc) happens to contain weird chars or spaces or dashes, my script will not be bothered and move on as usual.

But i just noticed that while it works with most paths, it will fail with paths that have a tilde as a shortcut to the user home dir. e.g:

```
# works
install dotfile "/home/user/.dotfile"

# fails
install dotfile "~/.dotfile"
# fails
cp dotfile "~/.dotfile"
```

The quotes are trying to protect against parsing the `~` itself. as it is trying to copy the file to `./~/.dotfile`

I want to use `~/` because it is convenient (and simple. and simple means less bugs), and enclose it in quotes because it is safe against spaces and dashes. Any way to have both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to use ~/ because it is convenient (and simple. and simple
>   means less bugs), and enclose it in quotes because it is safe against
>   spaces and dashes. Any way to have both?

Yes, it is good practice to use double-quotes.  Just don't put them around the `~/`.  Leave that part unquoted:

```
install dotfile ~/".dotfile"
```

#### Tilde Expansions and Difficult Home Directory Names

The `~` expansion uses the `HOME` variable.  Let's create a directory with difficult name and assign it to `HOME` and see how the shell behaves:

```
$ mkdir $'/tmp/spaces and\ttabs'
$ HOME=$'/tmp/spaces and\ttabs'
$ cd ~/
$ pwd
/tmp/spaces and tabs
```

Thus, it worked correctly.

Comment: but then that does not protect me if the `~` expansion is messed up.. even though that should be uncommon. yeah, i think this may be the best compromise.

Comment: @gcb In what scenario would you anticipate a "mess up"?  In my experience, the shell does tilde expansions safely and it does so even if `$HOME` contains spaces.

Comment: @gcb I just added to the answer an example of the shell correctly handling a 'difficult' tilde expansion.

Comment: yep! you are correct. i had just done a similar test `(HOME=/tmp/x\ x; BADFILE="x x";cp Makefile ~/"$BADFILE")` and it works fine! (where `(HOME=/tmp/x\ x; BADFILE="x x";cp Makefile ~/$BADFILE)` fails as expected. you nailed it! thanks

Comment: Something that helped me understand .. For unquoted variables put on the command line, Bash splits their value into distinct arguments if they contain chars found in _$IFS_ special variable, this is part of _variable expansion_ process. On the other hand, tild expansion simply expands the bare value of _$HOME_ into a single word. This means `~/somewhere` is equivalent to `"$HOME"/somewhere`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`eval`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/eval) like this to expand the `~/` to an actual full path to the file:

```
my_path=".dotfile"
eval full_path=$(printf "~/%q" "$my_path")
echo $full_path
```

Or try this:

```
eval full_path=$(echo "~/.dotfile")
echo $full_path
```

Comment: This seems an awfully complex solution to get the ~ parsed without quotes, but the rest of the path with quotes. Why not just put double-quotes around the rest of the path (as in John1024's answer)?